# Not able to connect local mysql server

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I am getting this exception while trying to connect mysql from my java application

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$3.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:765)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:285)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at net.xxx.fetch.jobboard.WebDBMaintainer.getMasterEnable(WebDBMaintainer.java:717)
    at net.xxx.net.MasterEnableCache.refreshCache(MasterEnableCache.java:80)
    at net.xxx.net.MasterEnableCache.setMachineID(MasterEnableCache.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:856)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:734)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:886)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValues(BeanWrapperImpl.java:913)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValues(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:330)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:317)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:230)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:156)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderServlet.init(ContextLoaderServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:968)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1646)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:2388)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2309)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1545)
    ... 49 more
```

My context configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/abc" >

<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="50" maxIdle="15" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/abc" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;autoReconnect=true&amp;connectTimeout=10000&amp;integratedSecurity=true" validationQuery="SELECT 1" username="abc"  password="abc"/>
</Context>
```

If I try connecting to MySQL using

```
mysql -uabc -h 127.0.0.1 -D db -pabc
```

It works fine

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Make up your mind. Is the data base name `db` or `database_name`?

Comment: it is db not database_name, let me update it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to MySQL database from tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735224/cant-connect-to-mysql-database-from-tomcat)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because of, mismatch version of mysql and jar dependeny in your code. 
Use this sql connector version of 5.1.46 or above.

Answer (score -1):

change the  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&connectTimeout=10000&integratedSecurity=true"
to
url="jdbc:mysql://**127.0.0.1**:3306/db?characterEncoding=UTF-8&autoReconnect=true&connectTimeout=10000&integratedSecurity=true"

Comment: That will not make any difference unless the local hosts file is misconfigured, in which case the correct solution is to fix the hosts file.